# How to get US work authorization for new recruits?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, relocation, visa, international

Say, you're recruiting a person from [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India) and wanted him to join your company in [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States).

In such case:

- What does it take to get this authorization?
- How long might it take?
- Is there additional cost to the employer?

Comment: Get an immigration lawyer.

Comment: @user1220 That seems to be an ultimate advice ;) I still need to understand the process.

Comment: There are so many variables that it isn't funny. It depends heavily on the specific country, and yes, there will be anywhere from 5 to 10k cost to the employer

Comment: @user1220 I understand. I have updated the question. And the country is India

Comment: While I think this question is on-topic here, you might search the [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com) for related info as well. Please don't cross-post though.

Comment: @DavidK I'm *just* looking for a rough idea. Someone on [us](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users) might have faced such a situation

Comment: @DavidK Not Travel. Travel is for short-term things like vacations. [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) might take it, but they are more from the side of the person moving.

Comment: Here's a [short introduction](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/hiring-foreign-workers-your-business-first-things-know.html) from Nolo.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this being off-topic. Legal questions are normally fine if the subject matter is easily researched and it's something most managers or HR people should know. But foreign national immigration procedures are highly specialised it seems and it's probably too complex for our Q&A format.

Comment: I lean toward keeping it open.  The sordid state of affairs around the US H1B program is widely known.  If someone else asks a question about getting a job in Benin while living in Paraguay we can decide if that's too obscure separately.

Comment: I think [@user1220](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/1220/user1220) is right. Each industry will have it's own norms etc. A lawyer seems to be the best bet. At least I have a rough idea, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Typically you need to sponsor an H1B visa application. See http://www.workpermit.com/us/investor_h-1b.htm
2. It can take years. H1B are issued once a year and there is a lottery. The lottery makes it unpredictable.
3. Typically in involves an immigration layer to file the application. Many thousands of dollars

Comment: Is H1B the only visa-type? I have heard of cases when people get the visa in days.